# I deleted folder in / and I want to make the folder exist again. Does it start with Capital letter (SEE picture)

Tags: file-system

`I deleted the folder symlinking to /storage/sdcard0 and I want to restore the symlink but I'm not sure if I should make new folder starting with s or S

there should be folder named ?dcard does it start with S or s?
[image: c]

Comment: AFAIK, everything in root should start with a lowercase letter.  It helps to avoid things like `rm -rf /` oops, I hit enter instead of shift!

Comment: @Compro01 what do you mean by oops, I hit enter instead of shift!

Comment: Say you have a folder named "Rubbish" in your root.  You want to delete it and everything in it (It's rubbish, after all), so you type `rm -rf /Rubbish`, but when you type shift+r for the capital, you accidentally hit the enter key, instead of the shift key which is right below it.  And now rm is cheerfully running through your system deleting everything it can reach (probably starting with much of /bin) before you are able to hit crtl+c and stop it.

Comment: @Compro01 Im not sure I understand properly:so it will delete all files named rubbish in whole device or every file on whole device if I type in rubbish which doesnt exist but Rubbish does?

Comment: No, what I'm meaning is that because you accidentally hit enter instead of shift when you were trying to type the capital letter, is that you executed the command `rm -rf /`, which deletes **everything**.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `/sdcard`, with a lower-case `s`.

Answer (score 0):

I made a folder called /sdcard and wanted to `ln -s /sdcard /storage/sdcard0` but I got ln not found or something like that.So I `mount -o bind /sdcard /storage/sdcard0` **which made me unable to access the sdcard in anyway on my phone.** I was scared the sdcard got wiped because it was empty except it had a Root Explorer folder for a reason unknown to Me.

Being scared of wiped data I unplugged the cable and rebooted hoping it was a temporary error caused by the mount -o bind command.Fortunately it was and I also found out that the /sdcard has been restored properly automatically on boot (the restore wasnt cused by any command it is just how Android is made)